# Jenkins - desktop application's window size is bigger than xvfb's screen resolution

Tags: jenkins, xvfb

I am running GUI tests for a desktop application under Jenkins on a headless server. I am using jenkin's xvfb plugin. When I run the test I can see that xvfb's screen resolution is smaller than the application's window size.

Is there a way I can configure xvfb so that I can have my application scaled up to a bigger screen resolution.

I am new to jenkins and xvfb. I am really stuck with this problem. I have googled around for this solution and it seems like I need to use flux box for that. Can somebody please clarify if fluxbox is a pre-requisite to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried the option "Xvfb screen" in Build Environment of your Job's configuration to configure resolution and color depth of the created virtual frame buffer in the format WxHxD. For example: 1024x758x16.

Xvfb screen changes the screen resolution and pixel depth, it needs to be in WxHxD format (i.e. 1600x1200x24). The default is 1024x768x24.

Refer: https://plugins.jenkins.io/xvfb